# Replacing Polygon layer with extent of another polygon in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, feature-class, mergeshapes

I need to insert a multi-polygon feature class into an existing vector layer (replacing the entire area within the former's footprint).

Is there a better way than just DELETE then MERGE polygons (in ArcMap?)

Comment: In edit mode right click the feature, copy and paste into other fc